# issue when trying to limit a div movement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to limit the movement of the `div` with `class` player to still in the window when i move the div up/down i find out a similar question witch gave me this solution :

```
var maxlimited = Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(playerPosition), 298), 628);
```

but when i try to implement this with my code it doesn't work and i can't even move the div at all

here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8cgnf0ks/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is missing curly braces. Change

```
for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
var maxlimited = Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(playerPosition), 298), 628);
players[i].style.marginTop = maxlimited + "px";
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    var maxlimited = Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(playerPosition), 298), 628);
    players[i].style.marginTop = maxlimited + "px";
}
```

It was possible to omit `{}` when there was only one line of code `players[i].style.marginTop = maxlimited + "px";` after `for` loop but after you have added

```
var maxlimited = Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(playerPosition), 298), 628);
```

you need to include entire block into `{ ... }` block.

Comment: now when i click at any of the down/up button the div jump to the bottom and become fix there ..

Comment: Looks like boundaries `Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(playerPosition), 298), 628);` are not correct.